# How to write shell script to mount a sd card into a folder?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

I need to write a shell script which should run on startup.
In this script my aim is to mount my sdc dev into a folder .

Normally if run mount /dev/  /foldername on terminal it will mount

How can I do the same using shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount /dev/<device> /foo
exit 0
```

`#!/bin/bash` is the required shebang,

`mount /dev/<device> /foo` is the command and parameters,

`exit 0` exits cleanly

Change `/dev/<device>` and `/foo` to your desired paths, and `/bin/bash` to the shell you use.

Also remember to `chmod +x` your script to make it executable